# How do I grab json values using cypress request?

Tags: javascript, cypress

I have been looking at many stack overflow solutions but none seem to fix my issue. I wrote code in my commands.js so I could use the json values I am trying to extract throughout my test suite. Here is the code I am using to do so:

```
Cypress.Commands.add('setAuthToken', () => {
    cy.request('/this/is/my/jsonToken').then((res) => {
        cy.wrap(res.body.token).as('token')
        cy.get('@token').then((token) => {
            cy.log(token)
        })
    })
})
```

Keeps saying the value is undefined. When I console log or cy log just the "res.body" it logs the correct json body object but as soon as I try to grab a property it becomes "undefined". Any suggestions or help welcomed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be other factors at play, but I believe the core issue to be that the `res.body` is returned as a string, and not a JSON object. You can simply parse the object, and then you should be able to see the value.

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('setAuthToken', () => {
    cy.request('/this/is/my/jsonToken').then((res) => {
        cy.wrap(JSON.parse(res.body).token).as('token')
        cy.get('@token').then((token) => {
            cy.log(token)
        })
    })
})
```

Note: this implementation only solves your main issue of having the `res.body.token` as undefined. It may not solve any issues on storing and referencing the value later. Without more information in the quest, I can't adequately provide a suggestion for that.

Comment: Can't believe I didn't think of that. Thank-you!

Comment: Man, I know it's been an year and half, but your answer really helped me... and Here is your 1+ from my side.